# How can I save the currently playing video in VLC Media player?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I would like to save the current playing video in VLC to disk.

I DO NOT want to open a video from disk to convert/save, there is no video on disk. So the convert/save function does not seem to be able to do this.

I am saying this because all the answers to this question I could find say to use the convert/save function, but this function does not seem to be able to do this. It wants to open another file or stream, which is not what I want, I want to use the video that is now playing.

What I want is very very very simple. The video that is now playing in VLC is the video I want to save to disk. So this function should not ask me for a file or stream or anything else to open, all this function should ask is the folder and name where the video should be stored. Nothing else

So how can I do that please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VLC doesn't have a 'Save As...' style function to save the **currently playing** video, sorry. What it CAN do however is... a little different:

#### Record the currently playing video

Just like tape recorders of old, VLC offers functionality to 'record' whatever is currently playing to disk.

You have to enable **Advanced Controls** first. Go to View -> Advanced Controls. You will see these options appear:

[image: Record/Snapshot and other 'Advanced' buttons]

Now, whenever you start playing a DVD or other media, you can simply hit the Record button to start and stop recording. The files are saved your Documents folder in `.mpg` format i.e.:

```
C:\Users\{username}\Documents\
```

Using this method you can save entire files, or just specific snippets. It's up to you.

#### Sources

- [How-to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2686/how-to-copy-a-dvd-with-vlc-1.0/)
- [VLC Documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Receive_and_Save_a_Stream/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its the best option I got so far. But it does means I have to play the entire video after hitting the record button ? Also, how about sound and subtitles, will they be included in the recording ?

Comment: @GuidoG - yes, you have to watch the whole thing. If you are trying to save a stream and don't want to watch the whole thing, you'll need to use the 'Convert/Save' -> Network option to save a new file (you'll need the path to the stream). As for subtitles and sound - yes both should be recorded along with the video.

Comment: @GuidoG - How did you go? Did you get it saving as you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I managed to get the videos saved. Thanks.

Comment: ?where can you change the default record folder path...
I want to direct recording to other folder...

Comment: Apparently VLC3+Windows11 saves the recording as an `.mp4` in **`C:\Users\{username}\Videos`** (...and I can't find any option to choose another location)

Answer (score 2):

The video DOES exist somewhere on your hard drive.

Simply click View, Playlist, or use CTRL-L to bring up the Playlist window. There you'll see your current video on the playlist. Right click on the video and from there you can click Save, or Information, or Show Containing Folder, any one of which will get you to the existing file path.

[Screenshot of Playlist View within VLC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF5nh.png)

Comment: What if it isn't on a hard drive, but is a streamed video?

Comment: The video is NOT on a hard drive, it is streamed from an url. So this wont work. I tried to describe that in my question also

Comment: This method does work with streaming video, this should be the accepted answer (tested with an RTSP stream).

Comment: @DaniloRoascio: Depends on the source of the streaming video, apparently. Tested with a HTTP stream and CNR, the menu option is not even available *in that case*.

Comment: Great answer for me. I tried to extract an embedded video from a DOCX. It was not possible to play the file from the DOCX/word/embeddings folder by simply renaming the .bin file, but this way I found it under an exotic path in the Temp structure.  Thx.

Comment: This solution works for streams; however, it is terribly worded. **No**, the video does **not** necessarily exist somewhere on your hard drive, the e.g. stream file does. However, you can utilize this method to save the video file itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of downloading a youtube video via VLC **command line** options.  The video is played very fast and can finish in seconds.
The general format is:

vlc -vvv  ***YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL*** --sout file/ts:***YOUR_FILE_NAME***.mpg

*Example:*

```
vlc -vvv https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0hm-CebrzU --sout file/ts:yoram-ab.mpg
```

Details here: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Receive_and_Save_a_Stream/

Comment: This does not answer the question because the OP has ruled out, *this function should not ask me for a file or stream or anything else to open*.

Comment: Thank you @IsayReinstateMonica totally correct.